# Did JKR base her description of Smeltings Academy on a real school?

Tags: harry-potter

We get very little information about Smeltings Academy - the school where Dudley goes:

> Dudley had been accepted at Uncle Vernon's old private school,
>   Smeltings.
>
> ...
>
> That evening, Dudley paraded around the living room for the family in
>   his brand-new uniform. Smeltings' boys wore maroon tailcoats, orange
>   knickerbockers, and flat straw hats called boaters. They also carried
>   knobbly sticks, used for hitting each other while the teachers weren't
>   looking. This was supposed to be good training for later life.

**Is there a real-life equivalent of this school that JKR used as model? The thing with the stick seems really distinctive.**

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Smeltings Academy seems to be an amalgam of several famous English public schools; notably [Eton College](http://www.etoncollege.com/), [Harrow School](http://www.harrowschool.org.uk/), [Hill House School](http://www.hillhouse.doncaster.sch.uk/) and [The King's School](http://www.kings-school.co.uk/).

**Eton = Tailcoats**
[image]

**Harrow = Boater hats**
[image]

**Hill House = Awful colour-scheme & knickerbocker trousers**
[image]

**Kings School, Canterbury = Swagger Sticks**
[image]

Comment: TIL: Sir Cristopher Lee wanted to attend Eton, passed the entrance exam, but could not afford it.

Comment: I'm hoping no-one asks about the swagger sticks. I'm totally at a loss on that.

Comment: what about the swagger sticks?

Comment: @phantom42 - [Drat](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BgmDSb1-2wQ)

Comment: So she took the worst from several schools :) Nice job JKR!

Comment: Oh my gosh, even for girls. This is a travesty.

Comment: @phantom42 - See edit. The swagger sticks are peculiar to King's School, Canterbury although they're technically only carried by monitors.