# Can a student decline to be a prefect?

Tags: harry-potter

[This answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/234392/why-do-prefects-have-their-own-bath/234396#234396) argues that the prefects bathroom is an incentive for prefects. The implication is that students could choose to not be prefects, even if chosen by the administration. Yet from what we see it doesn't seem like prefects were offered a choice. With no prior warning new prefects simply received a letter and a badge making them prefects, and were supposed to show up for duty beginning on the train. Depending on the year, the notices might have arrived so close to the start of term that there wouldn't have even been time to send a return owl with any objections.

Yet it seems odd to unilaterally appoint someone to a position of authority/responsibility without consulting with the person at all, or giving the person the option to decline. Is there any evidence that students can or cannot decline the position of prefect?

Comment: Malfoy shows zero interest in his prefect duties in the sixth year.

Comment: But I bet, he likes the benefits.

Comment: I'm guessing they can, but there's no canon about that. It would be really weird if Hogwarts enforced the prefects, don't you think?

Comment: The heads of the houses simply know theirs wards well enough after four years to not select someone who would turn it down.